# To set Q27 for audio playback based on 8155

Tags: audio, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

There is now an audio algorithm module whose data processing format is 32bit Q27. This module needs to be added to the media playback audio link in the form of acdb. How do I set the bit width to match the algorithm module of Q27?

The current audio stream data format is 16bit. If you add the algorithm module directly, the audio will have the effect of accelerating playback.

I modified the audio corresponding configuration file (audio_io_policy.conf), but it still doesn't work.